# How to migrate PostgreSQL data from Postgres.app version to Homebrew-installed version

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, upgrade

I installed PostgresSQL (ver. 9.4) several years ago using Postgres.app but I'd like to use Homebrew to manage PostgreSQL from now on. I'm on Mac OS 10.14. I've installed the latest version (12.1) using Homebrew, and I'd like to know how to move my data to this new version. All the update guides I've read assume that the old and new versions were installed in the same location.

Data directories:

`/Users/robin/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.4`
`/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/12.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know where the `.../data/` directory of the Postgres.app lives (check your preferences), you should be able to use `pg_upgrade` to migrate from 9.4 to 12. You will need to do a fresh `initdb` of the v. 12 cluster first.

Here are some steps, based on your environment, assuming 1) postgres v. 12 is not running on your system (or you stopped it), and 2) you have not created a database in v. 12 yet:

```
export PGDATANEW=/Users/robin/pgsql/12/data # (or desired location)
mkdir -p $PGDATANEW
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/12.1/bin/initdb -D $PGDATANEW -U postgres
export PGDATAOLD="/Users/robin/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.4"
export PGBINOLD=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin
export PGBINNEW=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/12.1/bin
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/12.1/bin/pg_upgrade -U postgres
```

If you already have an existing v. 12 database, you will need to dump the data, save it off somewhere, and wipe the existing v. 12 data folder before performing the `initdb` step

**Option 2:** The other option is to `pg_dump`/`pg_dumpall` your 9.4 data to a file, then import it into your v. 12 database

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've added the data directory that the Postgress.app preferences gave me. I've also added the location of the Homebrew-installed version. I note that neither is called `data`. As for the `psql` binaries, I'm not sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: I got the following error when I ran `pg_upgrade`:

"could not open version file: /Users/robin/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres/var-9.4/PG_VERSION"

Comment: When you do `SHOW data_directory;` in Postgres.app, what do you get? And what does `ls /Users/robin/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres/var-9.4` show?

Comment: `SHOW data_directory` returns the same directory that was in the Postgress.app preferences. PG_Version is in that directory, along with many other files and folders.

Comment: Oh, maybe you need to be the Postgres user to run pg_upgrade. I need to try that out but prob can’t get around to it until tomorrow

Comment: You can also use `pg_dump`/`pg_dumpall` to save to file and import on the other end

Comment: @Robincognito I had a few typos in my instructions.  I updated--could you try again?

Comment: This time I got the following error:
"connection to database failed: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
could not connect to source postmaster started with the command:
"/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_ctl" -w -l "pg_upgrade_server.log" -D "/Users/robin/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.4" -o "-p 50432 -b  -c listen_addresses='' -c unix_socket_permissions=0700 -c unix_socket_directories='/Users/robin'" start"

Comment: you ran `pg_upgrade` with the `-U postgres` flag?

Comment: Yes. According to someone else who had this error, it's because the role "postgres" doesn't exist in PostgreSQL 9.

Comment: ok so if you're willing, then `CREATE ROLE postgres SUPERUSER` on your 9.4 instance before doing the `pg_upgrade -U postgres`.  Traditionally, the default superuser is `postgres`, but it seems in some distributions, it hasn't been that way.  Otherwise do `initdb -$PGDATANEW -U robin` and do `pg_upgrade -U robin`

Comment: I used the second method and got through a lot more checks this time but this error came up: lc_collate values for database "postgres" do not match:  old "en_US.UTF-8", new "en_GB.UTF-8"

Comment: Hmm, that's unfortunate.  Seems like Postgres.app made some assumptions.  Do you have a preference for your indexes to be collated with `en_US` or `en_GB`?  If not, the easiest workaround is to tack on `--lc-collate en_US.UTF-8 ` to your `initdb` step.  Otherwise, you can refer to this mailing list thread (and update your 9.4 database accordingly): https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/8209.1499713626%40sss.pgh.pa.us

Comment: I don't have a preference for en_GB so I set the locale to en_US and it upgraded successfully. Thank you very much for your help.